# Cannot nest aggregate operations

Tags: mysql, teradata

I am trying to run the following query :

```
Select T, COUNT(T) as CountOf, (COUNT(T)*100)/(SUM(COUNT(T))) AS percen FROM
(
select prod as T, x,y,z from table1
UNION ALL select prod as T, x,y,z from table2
UNION ALL select prod as T, x,y,z from table3
)
AS m
GROUP BY T ORDER BY COUNT(T) DESC;
```

The above query gives the error. I am able to run the query successfully without the 3rd parameter i.e. `(COUNT(T)*100)/(SUM(COUNT(T))) AS percent` (Calculates the percentage distribution of the 2nd parameter i.e. `CountOf`)

But when i include the percentage parameter, it gives error. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL, SQLServer and teradata are all different products - which one are you using? This is directly relevant to your question - there is an easier way to do what (I think) you want in SQLServer than in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `SUM` to a `SUM OVER`, but this is not supported by MySQL:

```
SELECT T, COUNT(T) AS CountOf, 
   (COUNT(T)*100)/(SUM(COUNT(T)) OVER ()) AS percen
FROM
 (
   SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table3
  ) AS m
GROUP BY T 
ORDER BY COUNT(T) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using distinct but if you are using sql server you can try

```
Select DISTINCT T, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T) as CountOf,  ((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T) * 100) / COUNT(*) OVER ()) AS percen FROM
(
select prod as T, x,y,z from table1
UNION ALL select prod as T, x,y,z from table2
UNION ALL select prod as T, x,y,z from table3
)
AS m
```

CTE option

```
WITH cteUnion AS (
    SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT prod AS T, x,y,z FROM table3
),
cteUnionWithTotalCount AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount FROM cteUnion
)
SELECT  T, COUNT(*) AS CountOf, ((COUNT(*) * 100)/ TotalCount) AS percen
FROM    cteUnionWithTotalCount
GROUP BY T, TotalCount
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Hi, the 2nd parameter becomes 1 of every row and the third parameter i.e percentage becomes 0 for every row.Still unable to figure it out.

Comment: are you still using your group by?

Comment: Yes i am using the group by clause

Comment: take out the group by clause

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I figured it out. The only issue is that many values are 0 because its trying to distributed 106 rows into percentage value. So the values having very high value gets a percentage number, rest all gets 0.